# FTP for iOS, how to download from FTP protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ftp, download

I have been using SampleFTP from Apple but I cannot understand the procedure, I mean, in other languages is simple as set the URL, Path, user and password then "navigate" and download or upload things to that Path... but I don't understand how to do in iOS... I don't have any NSFtp or whatever...

EDIT:
From the begining my #import "NetworkManager.h" does not work, error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can Use https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C13-Networking/15-FTP%20Helper

and

```
- (void) download
 {

  NSData *ftpData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[FTPHelper sharedInstance].filePath];
 }
```

Comment: Where do you specify the server, user, pass, path and filename? @spider1983 please, thanks.

Comment: there is a sample project in the repository i gave you, please go through that and try to follow the steps likewise...

Comment: Yes, I did but didn't work, and some static method are nos accesible my Xcode does not recognize it.. but don't worry I will keep looking for FTP or study the apple sample...

Answer (score 3):

There is also the Karelia [ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit). Free. Open Source and under active development.

Comment: Thanks for it, seems "easy".

Answer (score 1):

There is no FTP inbuilt library for iOS,but you can find custom librariews for that like tihis one http://code.google.com/p/ios-ftp-server/ or http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp

Comment: I liked chilkasoft but is for payment and I cannot afford for a small project, and I am currently reading the google one, thanks, I'm quite desperated with iOS.

Comment: its unfortunate that apple did not add any native FTP library for iOS

Comment: by the way, the google one is so deprecated but it's nice, and I have the same problem, cannot import networkController.h dunno why...